# How to add buttons to Windows 8 Toast Notification?

Tags: c#, windows-8, notifications, windows-runtime, toast

I am developing an app, and I am using windows 8 toast notification

My need is when the notification is shown I need two buttons on it; the first to dismiss(we have this one on the example down) and second one that will have an event implemented in my code  if the user press it I need to execute a code app.

Here is an example that shows tho buttons on the windows 8 toast notification 
but I can't rename the (snooze) button text and can't add its event handler in my code.

```
string toastXmlString =
"<toast duration=\"long\">\n" +
"<visual>\"<binding template=\"ToastText02\">\n" +
"<text id=\"1\">Alarms Notifications SDK Sample App</text>\n" +
"<text id=\"2\">" + alarmName + "</text>\n" +
"</binding>\n" +
"</visual>\n" +
"<commands scenario=\"alarm\">\n" +
"<command id=\"snooze\"/>\n" +
"<command id=\"dismiss\"/>\n" +
"</commands>\n" +
"</toast>\n";
```

Here's the result:

[image: demo]

Thank you

Comment: Please accept my answer if you feel good about it as there's no another answers :)

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 8.0/ 8.1 you can't do that because we don't have the 'Interactive' toast notifications, if you want to do it, you should upgrade to Windows 10.

[Adaptive/ Interactive Toast notifications - Windows 10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/07/02/adaptive-and-interactive-toast-notifications-for-windows-10.aspx)